# Problemas con el Servidor GlassFish 6.2.5, Apache Netbeans, Ubuntu 20.0.4

Tags: java, aplicación-web, server, glassfish

Estaba intentando hacer una prueba(Hola mundo) con Java Server Faces e inicie un proyecto web application con Maven,  y el servidor GlassFish y se descargo al arrancar el proyecto y hasta alli todo bien; me aparecieron unos errores al correr el proyecto que tenian que ver con el servidor, el proyecto salia con build success pero el servidor no se iniciabe, cambie varios parametros y creo que me equivoque en la configuracion y ya no me aparece ningun servidor dentro de las opciones de apache netbeans. Intento configurar el servidor de GlassFish en apache Netbeans 13 pero me sale el error de la foto. Instale por consola GlassFish la version 6.2.5, hice la prueba y funciona perfecto el servidor en el localhost:4848 Pero no encuentro como vicunlarlo a Apache Netbeans. desinstale el Netbeans y volvi a arrancarlo y nada

Existe alguna forma de habilitar los servidores en apache netbeans,El servidor de TomCat si por lo menos me deja pasar a la pantalla en donde me permite vincunlarlo con la carpeta en que esta instalado pero Glass ni siquiera me permite configurar nada.Creo un proyecto Web Application desde cero de java e intento seleccionar el servidor Glass y me sale lo mismo de la foto. Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda

[image: Esto es lo que me aparece cuando intento seleccionar GlassFish]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Desde el ID de trabajo Netbeans solo es posible agregar versiones específicas de GlassFish, entre las opciones puedes ver cuales puedes agregar.
Para resolver lo de la imagen solo debes cambiar el nombre del servidor, por ejemplo:
Name: Glassfish server 2.
El mensaje que te sale es porque ya existe un servidor instalado bajo ese nombre.

Comment: Hola @Steven Burgos, muchas gracias por responder, en algún video de youtube también planteaban esa solución, ya la había implementado y  nada, sin embargo la volví a realizar por si acaso y tampoco. Alguna otra sugerencia

Comment: Sin embargo probé con un servidor Tomcat y ese si me dejo agregarlo desde la carpeta donde la deje. Este servidor si funcionó sin problema

Comment: Con tomcat si vas a poder, pero con Glassfish solo puedes instalar hasta la versión 5.1 si no estoy mal, Netbeans no te permite instalar una posterior. Puedes intentar usar Glassfish con Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\Admin ve a esta dirección y buscas la carpeta GlassFish_Server y lo eliminas eso soluciono mi error, pero después tendrás que volver a instalar GlassFish manualmente.